# Apache Rewiterule Excluding Query String Keys

Tags: apache, web, mod-rewrite, browser, webserver

I have a Query String URL: ***http://example.com/stackoverflow?key1=a&key2=b&key3=c&key4=d&key5=e&key6=f***.

I am rewriting the Query String URL using Apache [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html), as shown bellow in [2]. However, I would like to exclude key1 and key4 from the variable %{QUERY_STRING} and pass all the other keys and their values to the URL that substitute the one in the browser like this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /stack?key1=a&(*)&key4=d&(*)
```

The RewriteRule above is supposed to rewrite all the {QUERY_STRING} keys and values, except key1 and key4, but it is not working. Anyone could give me an insight on how to achieve my goal? I tried using $1 and $2 between &, but did not work either.

[2]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) /stack?%{QUERY_STRING} 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: In other words you want to remove the `key1` and `key4` URL parameters from the URL? However, the example rule you gave explicitly _includes_ `key1` and `key4` in the target URL - so it would do the opposite? Can you please clarify what the resulting target URL should look like.

Comment: Key1 and key4 are keys in the source URL, therefore inside the variable %{QUERY_STRING}, but I want these keys to receive a new value when parsing them to the URL that will substitute the source URL. Actually key1=file.txt and key4=file.png values are filenames, when the value is passed to key1 and key4 on the url that will replace the source, I want to append the file path key1=/file/path/file.txt and key4=/file/path/file.png